# How to show an item from an array in json to a react native modal unique on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of data stored in a JSON file. It has ID, title and description. Now I have listed out the titles in my ReactNative app. I want to display the content of each title on a modal. How can I do that?

Below is my code where the modal will come up, but the description won't appear on the modal. Instead it gives an error that it's not defined.

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {

  Modal,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,

  View,
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const data = require("./dummyData.json");

  let modalData = [];
  const [showStanzas, SetshowStanzas] = useState(false);
  const onpressHandler = function (a, b) {
    modalData = data[b];
    SetshowStanzas(true);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headingView}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}></Text>
      </View>

      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <View style={styles.container3}>
            {data.map((datas, id) => {
              return (
                <View key={id}>
                  <Text
                    style={styles.hymnTitle}
                    onPress={() => {
                      onpressHandler(true, id);
                    }}
                  >
                    {datas.id}. {""}
                    {datas.title}{" "}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              );
            })}
            <Modal
              animationType={"slide"}
              visible={showStanzas}
              onRequestClose={() => SetshowStanzas(false)}
            >
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.desc}> {modalData.description} </Text>
              </View>
            </Modal>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please, summarize your question in the title and give details (what have you tried, what does the logs / docs say, ...) within the description section.

Comment: Thanks boss....I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrate the local variable `modalData` to a React state

```
const [mobileData, setMobileData] = useState();
```

Then store the selected index data on the on `onpressHandler`

```
const onpressHandler = function (a, b) {
    setMobileData(data[b]);
    SetshowStanzas(true);
};
```

Your modal code should work afterwards

Comment: Yea.... Sorry am late , I just figured it out before seeing this comment and it's just same state issue .....in all, thanks so much and am grateful.